# How to draw map AFTER you call async task and onPostExecute?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask

Hi I'm new to android and I created an app with a map and when the user touches on a country it navigates to another activity that displays the country's name,city, population etc.

Below that I want to draw a map that has a marker on the country's city.

Almost everything is working except that I have to hardcode the city because I realised onMapReady is called before onPostExecute?But I called it before I called mapReady.Get country details just gets the country's city, name etc.

In my OnCreate:

```
 final String selectedCountry = getIntent().getStringExtra("country");


    new GetCountryDetails().execute(selectedCountry);


    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

In my onMapReady:

```
LatLng capitalCity = getCityLatitude(this,city);
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(capitalCity));

    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(capitalCity).title(city);
    googleMap.addMarker(marker);
```

Is there a way to fix this?Any help will be appreciated

Comment: can you post you full code here?

Answer (score 0):

Put the code snippet below in your `onPostExecute` method:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```